# GCP external IP drop after maintenance

Tags: networking, ip, google-compute-engine, vpc

I have an external IP set to one of my cluster, and sometimes the rule just drop without identified reason. Sometimes it happens after the maintenance period, but sometimes it does not.

Do you have any idea why the external IP drop or any clue to understand what happened ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look at Stackdriver logs which can give better insights.

Also, you can assign static public external IP so that your IP dont change.
See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Comment: I have assigned a static external IP address to my VM instance, that's why I don't understand why sometimes the rule drops and I have to reset myself. Didn't find anything particular in Stackdriver execpt my own modifications.